# Is there a way to speed up python's Tkinter/Pillow Tkimage.Photoimage?

Tags: python, performance, tkinter, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I'm currently trying to make fancy widgets for Tkinter and for this i made an image collection of 40x50 images (240x240 pixels, RGBA). When i try to load all these images (they are in a pickle file, already containing pillow images), it takes way over a minute for this simple loop to execute, where `ImageTk.Photoimage` seems to be the bottleneck:

```
imagearray = pickle.load(open(self.GAUGE_UI_FILENAME, "rb")) #40x50 array of 240x240 pixel RGBA images
converted_imagelist = []
    for imagelist in imagearray:
        for img in imagelist:
            converted_imagelist.append(ImageTk.PhotoImage(img, size = (240,240)))
        self.gauge_images.append(converted_imagelist)
        converted_imagelist = []
```

I already tried threading it, but it seems like `ImageTk.PhotoImage` calls functions of Tkinter which only are allowed to run in the main thread. **Am i doing something wrong? Can i somehow prepare the images for tkinter to reduce the startup time?** The unpickling of the rather large nested list happens in a split second, but the conversion for tkinter takes ages.
After the images are loaded i can cycle through them fine in a reasonable amount of frames per second to display the animations but the execution time of this few lines of code makes me go grab a Tea before the application actually shows the GUI.

Comment: Threading won't speed it up. If anything, it will slow it down.

Comment: If the pickle file contains already resized (240x240) images, the time to create those `PhotoImage` should not be long.

Comment: A solution is starting a short animation for user and use root.after() to load all frames in the background using, for example, a generator.

Comment: @acw1668 The size of the original images is already 240x240

Comment: @Aleksander Bauer
If you're still here, look there. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70986295/python-imagetk-photoimage-slow-loading-of-png-with-alphachannel